# URL link to # page position and Owl Carousel slider position

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, external, owl-carousel

I have several links to send out to clients that reference # positions on my html site (http://www.sound.co.uk). I'm using javascript to convert some client-friendlier urls to specific ID tags on the page.

e.g

```
if (window.location.hash == "#services") {
navigationFn.goToSection('#audio-services');     
}
```

listens for "....#services" and re-directs to "....#audio-services"

or

```
if (window.location.hash == "#quickrates") {     
navigationFn.goToSection('#rates-section');
window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY - 100);
$('#ratesModal').modal('show');
}
```

directly opens a bootstrap modal window.

The problem is linking to specific slides on my Owl Carousel.

```
if (window.location.hash == "#studio6") {   
window.location.hash = '#studio-6-podcasts-adr-games-animation-audio';
navigationFn.goToSection('#studio-6-podcasts-adr-games-animation-audio');
window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY - 75); 
}
```

will do it, but then when I cycle through the slides the Owl Carousel goes haywire; missing out slides, or showing blank ones.

Here's my Owl js:

```
$("#owl-slider-home").owlCarousel({
      slideSpeed : 500,
      paginationSpeed : 500,
      singleItem : true,
      transitionStyle : false,
      afterInit : progressBar,
      afterMove : moved,
      loop : true,
      autoHeight: true,
      touchDrag : true,
      mouseDrag : true,
      navigation: true,
       navigationText: [
        "<i class='fa fa-angle-left'></i>",
        "<i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>"
        ]
    });
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<div class="bgslider-owl">

<div id="owl-slider-home" class="onStep owl-carousel" data-animation="fadeInRight" data-time="150">

<div class="item" id="studio-6-podcasts-adr-games-animation-audio" name="studio-6-podcasts-adr-games-animation-audio">
<div class="container">

etc..
```

I have jQuery OwlCarousel v1.3.3 and jQuery v3.1.0

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Try to stop autoplay

Comment: Take a look at https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html#to-owl-carousel . Example: carousel.trigger("to.owl.carousel", [0, 500, true]);